# Large files encryption: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have encryptor/decryptor and it worked well until I tried to add large files support.
I have javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption.

```
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

    public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    public static SecretKey generateKey(String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), EncryptionUtil.SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);

        return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
    }

    private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile,
                                 File outputFile) {
        try {
            Key secretKey = generateKey(key);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            for(int readBytes=inputStream.read(buff); readBytes>-1;readBytes=inputStream.read(buff)) {
                outputStream.write(cipher.update(buff,0, readBytes));
            }
            outputStream.write(cipher.doFinal()); // here we get IllegalBlockSizeException

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't explain your current problem but your code is buggy. First, you aren't specifying the full cipher transformation string with "ALGORITHM/MODE/PADDING", instead you're just specifying the "ALGORITHM". It's unfortunate that Java allows it but it does, with the result that you get provider defaults. These defaults can vary from provider to provider and platform to platform, making the code non-portable. Second, the lines `outputStream.write(cipher.update(buff,0, readBytes));` can throw a null pointer exception in certain cases, e.g. a file whose length %1024 is < 16.

Comment: Consider using CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream and Files.copy to make this cleaner, clearer and much shorter.

Comment: Please specify the exact data that causes the IllegalBlockSizeException, or at least the exact length of the file. Also provide the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I've tried several files and the result is the same. I've also tried CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream. The code is not working at all and that's the question. But thanks

Comment: It's working for encryption but decryption causes this exception